# How to build asymmetric keys from passphrase?

Tags: c#, encryption

I have many customers all of them have a password. For some of their information, I want to be sure that only them can read it (not even our developers our sysadmin or dba).

So I came up with this idea:

- On their next login build a public key from their password and store it on the DB.
- Every time a new information is added, encrypt it with this public key.
- When they want to read it, create the private key  from the password they just entered and decipher the information

I think I should use rfc2898derivebytes for creating my keys, but what I don't know is what should I save in db for my public key.

Comment: Have you looked at the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)? Looks like all you need is the password, salt and probably the number of iterations. You don't save the password (not unhashed & salted anyways), but get it from the user. So it seems you just need to save the salt and iteration count. - In the example, the key `k1` and the key `k2` are exactly the same, because they're built from the same password, salt and iteration count.

Comment: The exemple is using TripleDES  which is symetric, I need an asymetric version of this. I need asymetric because I don't have the suers password when I'm writing the informations.

Comment: [Here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/how-can-one-securely-generate-an-asymmetric-key-pair-from-a-short-passphrase) you will find few examples how to do it.

Comment: I think i'll go with the other answer from your link : generate 2 rsa keys, and save the private key cyphered with a symetric algorithm.